# renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present) error while installing ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, upgrade, update-manager, apturl

[image: here is where the updating lags]

I have been trying to update my Ubuntu 14.04LTS to Ubuntu 16, I tried updating using a USB stick as it says in the official site, but that didn't work, I wasn't even able to enter the boot mode, so I tried updating the normal way( I wanted to do a full re-installation, because I wanted to set everything up from the beginning  as i want it).
However while I'm waiting for the new Ubuntu to be installed, it just freezes here, and honestly I have no idea what to do. I'm a very new to all of this, so the more details the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so basically, I ditched upgrading and just installed ubuntu 16.04 from a USB stick, I lost the files that I had on my laptop, but that was okay by me, However, I didn't find a direct solution for this issue.